# R automatically add a slash before dollar sign in the formula block

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

formula block not display as expected in r studio for .rmd file

Before changing my .rmd from source to visual, my code looks good like this:

```
$$
\begin{align}
blah blah blah
\end{align}
$$
```

and the preview looks perfect.

But after I change to "visual", the formula block is not displaying and when I go back the source, my dollar signs are automatically added a slash and look like this:

```
\$\$ \begin{align}
blah blah blah
\end{align} \$\$
```

How can i avoid this?